# How to: select and insert parent child records without using loop in sql

Tags: sql, select, insert, parent-child

I have two Tables

```
OrderedStock
---
OrderID    Location
1          Richmond
2          Ohio
3          Queens


OrderItem
---
OrderItemID  OrderID   Name
1            1         Perfume
2            1         Blinds
3            2         Ball
4            3         Cabinet
```

What is the best approach if I have to copy all the records from these tables to the similar tables(PostedOrder and PostedOrderItem) preserving the correct PostedOrderId in PostedOrderItem table. In actual, I have around 45K rows in Order table to be copied and their nested OrderItem records are around 2 million.

Target Table and its data would look like this

```
PostedOrdered
---
PostedOrderID    Location
11               Richmond
12               Ohio
13               Queens


PostedOrderItem
---
PostedOrderItemID  PostedOrderID       Name
101                11                  Perfume
102                11                  Blinds
103                12                  Ball
104                13                  Cabinet
```

PostedOrderId and PostedOrderItemId are auto incremented Primary Keys in their respective tables.

Any best approach i should follow without looping thorough with a select satement?

Thanks in advance and apology for the drastic formatting.

Comment: This question is unclear.  Why would you need to loop in order to insert records to new tables?  A SQL `INSERT` will do the trick.  No looping required.

Comment: What do you mean by "Similar tables"?  What is the "Order table", you only have `OrderedStock` and `OrderItem`?  Are you trying to take rows from `OrderedStock` and put them in `OrderItem`?  Or trying to take rows from `OrderItem` and put them in `OrderedStock`?  Or trying to take rows from both of these tables and put them into another table?  Please show some sample output of your desired result.

Comment: Devlin: I have to copy both OrderStock and OrderItemTable into PostedOrder and PostedOrderItem tables respectively.

Source tables are 1. OrderStock  2. OrderItem
Target Tables are 1. PostedOrder 2. PostedOrderItem
Hope it clarifies the question Paul

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Posted Order table, you need to also include an "original id" column.  You haven't specified how the new id is to be generated, so I will assume it's an `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column.

Example table schema for `PostedOrder`:

```
PostedOrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Location VARCHAR(100),
OriginalID INT NOT NULL  /* This is the id from the original table  */
```

Insert records to this table:

```
INSERT INTO PostedOrder (Location,OriginalID)
SELECT Location, OrderID FROM OrderedStock
```

You can then **use the original id as a link** to get the new `PostedOrderID` for the `PostedOrderItem` table.

Example table schema for `PostedOrderItem`:

```
PostedOrderItemID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
PostedOrderID INT NOT NULL, /* foreign key to PostedOrder table */
Name VARCHAR(100)
```

Note:  If for any reason you need to keep the original id for the items table, you can also add a column for that.  It's not necessary for your insert.

Insert records to `PostedOrderItem`:

```
INSERT INTO PostedOrderItem (PostedOrderID, Name)
SELECT p.PostedOrderID, o.Name
FROM PostedOrder p
INNER JOIN OrderItem o ON o.OrderID = p.OriginalID
```

Comment: I don't need the original id. Both PostedOrderId and PostedOrderItemId are identity(1,1) columns. If you look into the target result in my origianl question (that i've updated lately) you will probably get a better idea of what I am after.

Comment: I simply need to copy some orders from the source and preserve them into new Posted tables (of course with their proper items)

Comment: @AliRaza - You **do** need the original id from the OrderedStock table in the PostedOrder table because it serves as a way to get the PostedOrderID in the PostedOrderItem table.  Once you've inserted your records, you can drop the original id column from PostedOrder, if you wish.

Comment: Got the clue - Will try it definitely, but still looking for a solution where I can avoid dropping of a column at the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my experience, this is the simplest approach.  You have 2 queries, and an optional column drop.  When I've done similar data migrations, I've kept the original id columns around for awhile in case there are any questions about how the new records relate to the old.  This gives you a built-in path for tracking down any problems.

Comment: Got it (y) - i think for time being, this is the right or may be the only approach i've got

Answer (score 1):

You can use two insert select   based on pivot table

```
insert into aTempTable (OrderItemID, OrderID, Name, Location) 
select a.OrderItemID,  a.OrderID,   a.Name,  b.Location 
from OrderItem as a 
inner join OrderedStock as b on a.OrderID = b.OrderID;


insert into  PostedOrder (OrderID, Location) 
select distinct OrderID, Location 
from aTempTable ;


insert into PostedOrderItem (OrderItemID, OrderID, Name) 
select OrderItemID,  OrderID,   Name
from aTempTable ;
```

If you need new OrderItemID  use this

```
insert into aTempTable ( OrderID, Name, Location) 
select    a.OrderID,   a.Name,  b.Location 
from OrderItem as a 
inner join OrderedStock as b on a.OrderID = b.OrderID;


insert into  PostedOrder (OrderID, Location) 
select distinct OrderID, Location 
from aTempTable ;


insert into PostedOrderItem ( OrderItemID, OrderID, Name) 
select OrderItemID,  OrderID,   Name
from aTempTable ;
```

Comment: That way I will be inserting the old/original OrderId(coming from OrderItem) into PostedOrderItem table. In PostedOrderItem, i need the newly generated (PostedOrderId) as a parentId

Comment: I have elaborated the question little further. Hope its more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but its not useful as
First insert statement is inserting duplicated orders in PostedOrder table. 
What I am after is kind of Select on Order then insert it into PostedOrder, get the newIdentity and attach it with all its nested Items while inserting it into PostedOrderItem.

Comment: hmm but insert into PostedOrderItem is again picking the OrderId from OrderStock not the new Id generated in PostedOrder :(

Comment: If you need new itemOrderId ... i have update the answer